# Common practice to follow while creating Xib files for Universal apps after iPhone5 release

Tags: iphone, ios

The common practice I followed earlier during creating XIB files for universal applications was as follows:

I create the Xib file for both iPhone and iPad. Name them as XibFile.xib and XibFile~ipad.xib. For iPhone 4/4s and iPad3 I used retina images, where ever required. So that covered all my UI designs. And also my clients needed the iPhone5 screens in letterbox mode. I did not use the Default-568h@2x.png. So life was going smooth at my end.
But now when Apple decided to stop supporting Letterbox mode since May 1([read this article](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/03/21/after-a-year-of-warnings-apple-will-no-longer-accept-any-apps-that-use-udids-as-of-may-1st/)), I needed Xib level changes for iphone5 screens also. So for now I used auto resizing in the Xib file, and used vertical expansion for all my screens, and that solved most of my issues.
Now please advice me the best practice in doing the XIB file creation, providing support to iphone5/4/4s and iPad.

1.) Design for iphone5, 4" screens and use auto resizing for iPhone 4/4s. This will not compromise in the clarity of the images I use.

2.) Create 2 different Xib files for iphone. One for the 4" iPhone5 and other for normal iPhone4/4s screens.

Please advice which is the best practice. Also please let me know, if there is some other way.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create multiple XIBs if the lay out is fundamentally different for the different devices.

If you can reuse the same XIB for both iPhone 4 and 5 with appropraite autoresizing behaviour, do so.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to check for different models of iphone or ipad and do the needful accordingly. You can check iphone versions using the below code.

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)]) {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

        if(result.height == 960) {
            NSLog(@"iPhone 4 Resolution");
            resolution_number = 1;
        }
        if(result.height == 1136) {
            NSLog(@"iPhone 5 Resolution");
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Standard Resolution");
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are saying to maintain different Xib files. Say: 1.) XibFile.xib 2.) XibFile~iphone5.xib and 3.) XibFile~ipad.xib

Comment: it will be easier. Else you will have to dynamically change size of every item in xib, which can get pretty complicated.

Comment: But I think it depends on the images you have to use in the Xib files. In the application that I referred to above, it had a lot of static Xib files in it. And the images mostly were plain button images. So on resizing those, they did not seem to loose any clarity and nothing went pixelated. Point to be noted here is, I first designed for iPhone4 and then auto resized for iphone 5.

Comment: So for simple images in the Xib files, I think its always better to go for autoresizing. But if there are lot of images, and if there are chances that it looks distorted on auto resizing, we could go for the approach you have mentioned.

Comment: yes you are right there. You need to keep multiple xib only in the case of autoresizing not working properly. If it works for you, then that is indeed better.

Answer (score 0):

Using auto resizing is a good solution, it keeps your interface definitions and code simple and minimal. There would probably be very few differences between the 4 & 5 XIB files.

The area you're likely to see issues using this method is where you have scroll views defined in the XIB **where the content size is specified only in the XIB**. In this case you'll need to add a bit of code to calculate the content size and possibly resize the content as autoresizing won't cover it.

Comment: struts/springs work fine on the older iPad, they are used by auto-reiszing - you are thinking of auto-layout, which you do not have to use to have screens expand or contract.

Answer (score 0):

Take different xib and put this coding you can easily manage.

```
        //Device Compatibility
        #define g_IS_IPHONE             ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] )
        #define g_IS_IPOD               ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"] )
        #define g_IS_IPAD               ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPad"] )
        #define g_IS_IPHONE_5_SCREEN    [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 1024.0f
        #define g_IS_IPHONE_4_SCREEN    [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 480.0f && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 568.0f 



     if(g_IS_IPHONE_5_SCREEN)
     {
              DashboardViewController* deshObj=[[DashboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashboardViewController" bundle:nil];
     }
     else if(g_IS_IPHONE_4_SCREEN)
     {
            DashboardViewController* deshObj=[[DashboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashboardViewController4" bundle:nil];
     }
     else if(g_IS_IPAD){
             DashboardViewController* deshObj=[[DashboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashboardViewControllerIpad" bundle:nil];
     }
     else{
           DashboardViewController* deshObj=[[DashboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashboardViewController" bundle:nil];
      }
```

you can easily put your condition